# App cannot access translation files in engine or gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I tried every combination I can think of but I cannot get my app to see the localized content provided by my engine. Now the engine does just fine.

I see the same problem with `Rails_admin`.  Where it's i18n files are in a separate gem.  The main app cannot seem to see the files. I'm sure there must be an error in how I'm specifying the `I18n.load_path`, but it's got me beat.

from Ryan Bates rails cast:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('config', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

And one of my hack attempts:

```
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('**','locales', '**', '*.{rb,yml}')]
```

And any reference from inside the app results in a translation not found.

Any clues.

Comment: where are the locale files generated from your engine.

Comment: they are in config/locales.  I've copied them to lib/locales and root/locales to no avail.

Comment: please add them to the question so others can help

Comment: this appears to be a problem with the local development environment.  When the app is deployed, it works.  Not sure why

Comment: @bobbdelsol could you solve it for development? I have the same problem and it still works only for production environment.

Answer (score 19):

I was facing same issue , If your developing rails engine then add following lines to lib/engine_name/engine.rb

```
module MyEngine
  class MyEngine < Rails::Engine
    config.before_initialize do                                                      
      config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{config.root}/config/locales/**/*.yml"]
    end
  end
end
```

Another way

```
module MyEngine
  class MyEngine < Rails::Engine
    initializer 'MyEngine', before: :load_config_initializers do
      Rails.application.config.i18n.load_path += Dir["#{config.root}/config/locales/**/*.yml"]        
    end
  end
end
```