# Dynamically loading I18n translations from gem into Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, i18n-gem

I've created a gem (TranslationsGem) which I use in multiple projects (an engine and a Rails app). This gem sets up several hashes which are loaded into the I18n backend.

A method `#store_dynamic_translations` sets up several hashes which are loaded into the I18n backend. It basically works like this:

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, { test: { property: 'value' } })
```

My tests confirm the method and translation loading works correctly. I can't however get it to work in the host engine and Rails app.
In my test environment I have to execute the method in my `test_helper` to ensure the translations are loaded correctly. Outside the test environment I cannot seem to get it working correctly. I can verify that the method is executed, but the translations aren't loaded.

I have tried numerous things for hours, like executing the method in the [Engine initializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986512/app-cannot-access-translation-files-in-engine-or-gem) and using ActiveSupport hooks. In the host Rails app I tried executing the `#store_dynamic_translations` in an initializer but to no avail.

Oddly enough, if I execute the `#store_dynamic_translations` in my Rails app controller or view, it works. Is there any way to set this up at app boot time?

---

EDIT: I've setup an [example repository which contains the current setup](https://github.com/richardvenneman/engine-i18n-gem-loading).

1. A Gem which dynamically stores translations into the I18n backend.
2. A Rails Engine which loads the gem and should have its translations available

In [the test in question](https://github.com/richardvenneman/engine-i18n-gem-loading/blob/master/blorgh/test/translations_test.rb) uncommenting the `MyI18n::Translations.store_dynamic_translations` directive makes the test pass. But it should be possible to do from within an [engine initializer](https://github.com/richardvenneman/engine-i18n-gem-loading/blob/master/blorgh/lib/blorgh/engine.rb) I think?

Comment: I wrote an SO answer on the different ways to add translations, you might want to try creating a specific translation backend and add it using chaining  as describes here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25386964/how-to-add-values-dynamically-to-i18n/25387302#25387302

Comment: Rails has an after_initialize hook that you can call. Or you can call this in a before_action block in your applications controller.

Comment: @EmilKampp it looks like the `after_initialize` actually works from the test I ran just now! As opposed to all the other hooks that I tried. Will try to verify this today.

Comment: Nice. Let me know how that goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Emill Kampp's suggestion, the correct hook was `after_initialize`. I specified this in `engine.rb`:

```
module Blorgh
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace Blorgh

    config.after_initialize do
      MyI18n::Translations.store_dynamic_translations
    end
  end
end
```